# get locator from a hover element

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

I want to get the locator of this element (5,126,
601) but seem cant get it normally.

I think it will have to hover the mouse to the element and try to get the xpath but still I cant hover my mouse into it because it an SVG element . Any one know a way to get the locator properly?
here is the link to the website: https://fundingsocieties.com/progress

[image]

Comment: Also update the question with the Code which you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clicking on each node in turn will lead to the accompanying text being placed in the *highcharts-label* element.  This text can then be retrieved and the Quarter (1st tspan) be linked to the Total value (4th tspan) that you desire.

```
url="https://fundingsocieties.com/progress"
driver.get(url)
chart = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@data-highcharts-chart='0']"))
        )
markers = chart.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*[local-name()='g'][contains(@class,'highcharts-markers')]/*[local-name()='path']")
for m in markers:
    m.click()
    try:
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[local-name()='g'][contains(@class,'highcharts-label')]/*[local-name()='text']"))
        )
        tspans = element.find_elements(By.XPATH, "./*[local-name()='tspan']")
        if len(tspans) > 3: 
            print ("%s = %s" % (tspans[0].text, tspans[3].text))
    except TimeoutException:
        pass
```

The output is as follows:

```
Q2-2015 = 2
Q3-2015 = 12
....
Q1-2022 = 5,076,978
Q2-2022 = 5,109,680
Q3-2022 = 5,122,480
Q4-2022 = 5,126,601
```

Comment: Thanks, man, I tried your code in a new project without apply any pom into it and it worked but when I tried it in my code it failed, wierd

Answer (score 2):

Well, this element is updated only by hovering over the chart.
This is the unique XPath locator for this element:

```py
"//*[name()='text']//*[name()='tspan' and(contains(@style,'bold'))]"
```

The entire Selenium command can be:

```py
total_text =  driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[name()='text']//*[name()='tspan' and(contains(@style,'bold'))]").text
```

This can also be done with this CSS Selector: `text tspan[style*='bold']`, so the Selenium command could be

```py
total_text =  driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "text tspan[style*='bold']").text
```

Well, CSS Selector looks much shorter :)

Comment: Thanks for fast respond, I will try it later after work, but this xpath could get the value of 5,126, 601 in the chart right?

Comment: Sure. You can shortly open the link and find that element with dev tools

Comment: hi, I did try and got :"selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[name()='text']//*[name()='tspan' and(contains(@style,'bold'))]"} ". could you attach your code for me? thanks

Comment: Sure, but could you first share your code in the question?

Comment: https://github.com/JasonTrann/testFS here is the link to my code
the function "statistics_page.total_fund()" is the function i used for the quesion

Comment: Hm.. I see. I need to make some investigations to make this code working. Will do that later today

Comment: I hope so, but I see we indeed have to hover over the chart to make that element appear

Comment: If i did it manually, It would be like this: go to the source tab of dev tool, hover the mouse to Q4-2022 point, F8 to pause the browser, back to element tab and then i can get the value but i seem cant apply the step to code, link the image below
https://ibb.co/KqJ4Tjz